# How does a mobile-background-loop implemented?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried to search online but can not find the way to implement a mobile-background-loop like ones in https://verily.com/, notice how the colors changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS's `@keyframes` to make gradient animation. Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #ffc800, #41a93e, #00b2fe, #9300fe, #fe009f);
  background-size: 1000% 1000%;

  -webkit-animation: bg-gradient-animate 44s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: bg-gradient-animate 44s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: bg-gradient-animate 44s ease infinite;
  animation: bg-gradient-animate 44s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bg-gradient-animate {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-moz-keyframes bg-gradient-animate {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-o-keyframes bg-gradient-animate {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@keyframes bg-gradient-animate { 
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
.BackgroundFading {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background: black;
    animation: fading 4s infinite;
   -webkit-animation: fading 4s infinite;
}
@keyframes fading {
    0%   { background: black; }
    33%  { background: red; }
    66%  { background: blue; }
    100% { background: black; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fading {
    0%   { background: black; }
    33%  { background: red; }
    66%  { background: blue; }
    100% { background: black; }
}
```

See also: https://jsfiddle.net/a3xttweu/